# Submit main form without submitting an inner form

Tags: html, forms, jsf, jsf-2

i have a main form that contains an inner form (that inner form appears in edit case only)
and i want both forms to be separated from each other, than when submitting the main form the inner is not submitted, how to do so ?

here's a snippet:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">

  <!-- some inputs here -->

  <h:commandButton value="submit main" action="#{myBean.mainSubmit()}" />

 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{myBean.editMode}"> 
    <h:form id="innerForm"> 
      <!-- some inputs here -->

      <h:commandButton value="submit inner" action="#{myBean.innerSubmit()}" />
    </h:form>
 </h:panelGroup>

 </h:form>
```

**Current Behavior**: when submitting mainForm the inner form is submitted too, but when submitting the inner form the main is not submitted.

**Desired Behavior**: when submitting the mainForm the inner is not submitted, and when submitting the inner, the main doesn't get submitted too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested Forms are not something that you really want to have in your pages...

How about this approach? wrap in two panels and use ajax to execute/render them

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
 <h:panelGroup id="FirstPanel" rendered="#{myBean.editMode}"> 
  <!-- some inputs here -->
  <h:commandButton value="submit main" action="#{myBean.mainSubmit()}" >
      <f:ajax execute="FirstPanel" render="FirstPanel"></f:ajax>
  </h:commandButton>
 </h:panelGroup>

 <h:panelGroup id="SecondPanel" rendered="#{myBean.editMode}"> 
   <!-- some inputs here -->
   <h:commandButton value="submit inner" action="#{myBean.innerSubmit()}" >
       <f:ajax execute="SecondPanel" render="SecondPanel"></f:ajax>
   </h:commandButton>
 </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

You can place as many `<h:panelGroup` that you want and add their id's in the render execute of your f:ajax for example `f:ajax execute="FirstPanel ThirdOne AnotherOne"`...

Comment: Nested forms should definitely be avoided. Their behavior is unpredictable and differs from one browser to another.

Comment: To be more precise, it's illegal as per HTML specification.

Comment: are there any other workarounds like ignoring validation in innerForm or hide the innerForm or preventing it from submit when submitting the mainForm ?

Comment: You really should not try to find workarounds to enable illegal behavior, (I'm not aware of any workarounds )

Answer (score 0):

i faced a problem with the inner form on IE9, that the contents of the form is not displayable so i removed the inner form and used the partialSubmit feature of icefaces, and that solved the problem.

Comment: Nested forms are illegal in HTML. You should never have them in your webpages. The browser behaviour is unspecified.

Comment: @BalusC, yes you are right, i was just sharing my experience with them.